# Paragraph circle shapped

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to get my paragraph tag circle shapped using CSS3? Something like this: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-page-floats/heart1.png

```
<p>Here's my paragraph</p>

p {
  border-radius:50%
}
```

This doesn't works obviously.

Anyone knows a way to do this with CSS3?

Comment: Because paragraphs aren't square by default. You have set height and width to be the same.

Comment: Nope, that's not the case. The border-radius doesn't work at all on a <p> tag..

Comment: @Sebastiaan Um, yes it does: http://jsfiddle.net/2Lfahuvz/ However that has nothing to do with getting the text inside the paragraph to reflow into a circle. You're more or less out of luck there.

Comment: You need to define whether you want the *text* to flow in a circle shape or just have the text inside a circle. (For the latter, @Rawb92’s answer is good. For the former, there are only very awkward ways, based on having stripes of fillers on both sides.)

Comment: There is a reason why “page floats” are being developed: there is no reasonable way to do such things now.

Comment: @user3790069 That tutorial seems to be about wrapping text around an image or an object not wrapping the text inside an element. As far as I'm aware there is no easy way to do what Sabastiaan wants to do in CSS3 just yet.

Comment: @Rawb92 Ok, I'm sorry, I misunderstood Sebastiaan

Comment: @Rawb92  No, user3790069 is right, you can use exclusions to get what the OP wants. The exclusions can be shape-outside and shape-inside, and the later can be used to wrap text inside a circle or a heart. But browser support isn't high

Comment: @user3790069 You are right, see my coment above

Comment: Thanks all for thinking along, I really hoped there was an easy CSS3 solution but i gues there isn't.. yet.

Comment: solution in the near future: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JSaMl2OKjfQ (scroll for 7th min)

Comment: Closest I've seen to a current solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17716400/230390

Answer (score 2):

As Paulie_D has said in his comment, you need to set the paragraphs width and height in order for it to appear as a circle.

```
p {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

I have quickly thrown together an example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/s99rpt20/

You also need to set either a background color or a border (or both) or else you will be unable to see the radius as by default a paragraph does not have a background color!

Comment: I think my question isn't clear. Sorry for that. I mean more something like: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-page-floats/heart1.png