# Wrap text inside a circular div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to accomplish something like this:

[image]

I've tried creating a div and giving it a `border-radius` of `50%`. The problem is that the text overflows the corners of the circle.

How can I accomplish this, so that the whole circle could be filled up without overflow?

Comment: Question already asked without an accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057714/css3-circle-with-text-wrap

Comment: Or there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681361/how-to-make-a-text-inside-a-circle-div-fitting-correctly-where-div-size-is-not

Comment: Did you actually copy that image from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17716400/511529)? :-o

Comment: You will have to add <br> where needed, to adjust margins/paddings, etc... no perfect, pure CSS solution, it seems.

Comment: @GolezTrol I found the image on google images, but it must have came from that answer, haha. That answer does not have a solution anyway.

Comment: Is there a Javascript solution?

Comment: That answer shows quite an elaborate explanation of the limitations of the CSS proposal and the alternatives using SVG and canvas. If it doesn't work for you, please ask a new question which describes why the given answer doesn't work for you.

Comment: @GolezTrol, text is not selectable, for example... :)

Comment: @sinisake I too can guess what issues there might be, but it's up to OP to specify which requirements they have.

Answer (score -1):

What about this?

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid #cceeff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 15px;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>HALLO MAN, WANNA IT?</div>
```

Comment: This will hide the overflow text, I want it to break down to the next line.